# Autostart random video script throws IndexError

Tags: python, python-3

I am trying to autoplay a random video from an attached usb volume upon boot on my Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2.

The following Python 3 script works within Thonny, popping a Tk message box with the randomly selected video. (I've commented out the opening of `omxplayer` and added `messagebox` for debugging purposes.):

```
from random import choice
import glob
import subprocess
from tkinter import messagebox

videos = []

for file in glob.glob('/media/pi/**/*.m4v', recursive=True):
    videos.append(file)

chosen = choice(videos)
print(chosen)

messagebox.showinfo('title', chosen)

# subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', (chosen)])
```

However, auto-starting this script from `/home/pi/.config/autostart/*.desktop` yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/video_autoplay.py", line 16, in <module>
    chosen = choice(videos)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 261, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you check for an empty list? Do you check if the media is mounted? etc.

Comment: This is a general Python question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the external volume was not fully mounting prior to the python script running. By adding the following to the top of the python script, I was able to delay the functionality of the script and ultimately continue the process:

```
import time
 
# Wait for 2 seconds
time.sleep(2)
```